# Error when passing a laravel route as a props in VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I want to use the blade syntax route() in a vue js component so i thought i should use something like this :

```
<nav-bar 
:user="{{ json_encode(Auth::user()) }}" 
:authPath= "{{ route('auth') }}">

</nav-bar>
```

but an error apear in the console :
app.js:86258 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token ':' in

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Try without : 
```<nav-bar 
user="{{ json_encode(Auth::user()) }}" 
authPath= "{{ route('auth') }}">
</nav-bar>```

Comment: yeah those works, tried it before but i need both of them to be props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to pass attributes to Vue component through markup. This is called data binding. Like

```
<nav-bar 
authPath="{{ route('auth') }}">
</nav-bar>
```

The other Vue way to pass the props is with the v-bind: or :(colon), and you have to use both double-quotes and single-quotes in this case.

```
<nav-bar 
authPath="'{{ route('auth') }}'">
</nav-bar>
```

Without both quotes, you will receive Vue warnings.

Comment: Please add some explanation to this code only answer. Why do you think this works, how does it work?

Comment: It works now, thanks! here's what i did :<nav-bar 
:user="{{ json_encode(Auth::user()) }}" 
:authpath= "'{{ route('auth') }}'">
</nav-bar>

Answer (score 1):

Your `{{ route('auth') }}` is eventually gonna return something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth` --> This is a string NOT an expression.

Simply remove the `:` like this `authPath="{{ route('auth') }}"`

Answer (score 1):

as @Digvijay said you dont need that : for authPath because its not a vue variable before its passed to vue it will converted to string (also @MuktiRaniGosh way is works too).

but you have another problem and thats is the " for user prop because of json syntax. use ' instead so the code will be

```
<nav-bar 
:user='@json(Auth::user())'
authPath="{{ route('auth') }}">

</nav-bar>
```

Comment: Yup i tried to pass it without the ':' and it works but i wanted it as a prop. @MuktiRaniGosh method works, so Thank you !

Comment: Couldyou explain the issue with json part? it seems to work fine when i do : <nav-bar 
:user="{{ json_encode(Auth::user()) }}" 
:authpath= "'{{ route('auth') }}'">
</nav-bar>